# CSS3 & jQuery folder tabs link to tabs from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I am using the design for my tabs from http://red-team-design.com/css3-jquery-folder-tabs/

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="tab1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>    
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1">...</div>
    <div id="tab2">...</div>
    <div id="tab3">...</div>
    <div id="tab4">...</div>
</div>
```

The tabs work great but I would like to directly link to the information in tabs 2,3,4, etc, rather than have have the user go to the page and then click a tab. I've tried using  in front of the header for that tabbed topic but it does not work.

Any suggestions on how I could call nameofpage.html#topicname directly?

Thanks in advance

**NEW:**  the real information is behind a firewall, so I had to create something that would show what I am talking about.  Take a look at the link below.  The desired outcome would be that each of the names on the list in the second paragraph would directly open the desired tab of the tabtest page:
http://www.claudia-morgan.com/sandbox/index.html

Comment: do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/sr0h6we3/

Comment: Are you are wanting the information under the tabs to come from an outside document? So if you click on tab2, for example, nameofpage.html will appear under that tab?

Comment: Please include a **complete** and **verifiable** example in your question. The code in your question should allow us to easily demonstrate the issue, however you haven't included anything more than the HTML markup - in this case we'll likely need some CSS and/or JavaScript as well. For more information, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Its difficult to give you a definitive answer without code to work with, but it seems what you could do is get the url via `window.location` and parse the url to get the id for the tab with `parser.hash;` (see https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561).  Then you can trigger the show/hide script using the id from the url.